# Better way to initialize and update deeply nested Hash

Tags: ruby, ruby-hash

I have a `Hash` and I want to insert some data into it at a deep level, but a key might be missing at any level. So, I am conditionally initializing it before updating its value at every level.

What would be a better way to write this or an approach that can make code less ugly?

```
data[:foo] ||= {}
data[:foo][:bar] ||= {}
data[:foo][:bar][:baz] ||= []
data[:foo][:bar][:baz] << 99
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use *hash autovivification*:

```
data = Hash.new { |h, k| h[k] = h.dup.clear }
#⇒ {}

# or, credits to @Amadan:
data = Hash.new { |h, k| h[k] = Hash.new(&h.default_proc) }
#⇒ {}

data[:foo][:bar][:baz] = 42
data
#⇒ {:foo=>{:bar=>{:baz=>42}}}
```

The trick used here is we use [`Hash#default_proc`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Hash.html#method-i-default_proc) to create nested keys.

For your case:

```
(data[:foo][:bar][:baz] = []) << 99
```

Comment: data[:foo][:bar][:baz] ||= [] => {:foo=>{:bar=>{:baz=>{}}}}

Comment: @BryanAsh so what? One obviously should not call `||=` on the hash with a `default_proc`, use `=` instead.

Comment: `Hash.new { |h, k| h[k] = Hash.new(&h.default_proc) }` is a bit more efficient.

Comment: Eh, credits, as if I invented it :D anyway, it's a known incantation, with a somewhat less known name: "hash autovivification".

Comment: I suppose that if `data` is a given non-empty hash one simply attaches a default proc. If one does so could there be side-effects? For example, what if the hash already had a default proc? Note that it would be necessary to use `h.key?(k)` to check if a key exists, rather than relying on `h[k].nil?`.

Comment: @mudasobwa perfect answer to the question. Kudos to Amadan too for more efficient approach. Just a note: It will set the keys in hash even if we just access `data[:foo][:bar][:baz]` before setting its value. Not a problem for me, but good to remember.

Answer (score 1):

One could use recursion.

```
def stuff_it(h, first_key, *rest_keys, val)
  if rest_keys.empty?
    (h[first_key] ||= []) << val
  else
    h[first_key] = stuff_it(h[first_key] ||= {}, *rest_keys, val)
  end
  h
end   

stuff_it({ a: 1 }, :foo, :bar, :baz, 99)
  #=> {:a=>1, :foo=>{:bar=>{:baz=>[99]}}}
stuff_it({ a: 1, foo: { b: 2 } }, :foo, :bar, :baz, 99)
  #=> {:a=>1, :foo=>{:b=>2, :bar=>{:baz=>[99]}}}
stuff_it({ a: 1, foo: { b: 2, bar: { c: 3 } } }, :foo, :bar, :baz, 99)
  #=> {:a=>1, :foo=>{:b=>2, :bar=>{:c=>3, :baz=>[99]}}}
h = { a: 1, foo: { b: 2, bar: { c: 3, baz: [88] } } }
stuff_it(h, :foo, :bar, :baz, 99)
  #=> {:a=>1, :foo=>{:b=>2, :bar=>{:c=>3, :baz=>[88, 99]}}}
h # => {:a=>1, :foo=>{:b=>2, :bar=>{:c=>3, :baz=>[88, 99]}}}
```

As one can see from the last example, the method is destructive. It can be made non-destructive by making a small change.

```
def stuff_it(g, first_key, *rest_keys, val)
  h = g.merge(g)
  if rest_keys.empty?
     h[first_key] = h[first_key] ? h[first_key].dup << val : [val]
  else
    h[first_key] = stuff_it(h[first_key] ||= {}, *rest_keys, val)
  end
  h
end   

h = { a: 1, foo: { b: 2, bar: { c: 3 } } }
stuff_it(h, :foo, :bar, :baz, 99)
  #=> {:a=>1, :foo=>{:b=>2, :bar=>{:c=>3, :baz=>[99]}}}
h #=> { a: 1, foo: { b: 2, bar: { c: 3 } } }

h = { a: 1, foo: { b: 2, bar: { c: 3, baz: [88] } } }
stuff_it(h, :foo, :bar, :baz, 99)
  #=> {:a=>1, :foo=>{:b=>2, :bar=>{:c=>3, :baz=>[88, 99]}}}
h #=> {:a=>1, :foo=>{:b=>2, :bar=>{:c=>3, :baz=>[88]}}}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But as per my need, i think i'll go with mudasobwa's answer for now. May be later. :)

Answer (score 0):

You could also do something like:

```
class SpecialHash < Hash
  def [](key)
    if has_key?(key)
      super(key)
    else
      self[key] = self.class.new
    end
  end
end

h = SpecialHash.new
h[:foo][:bar][:baz] = "Baz"
h # => {:foo=>{:bar=>{:baz=>"Baz"}}}
```

It duck types exactly the same as a `Hash`.

You can reformat the same code as:

```
class SpecialHash < Hash
  def [](key)
    return super if has_key?(key)
    self[key] = self.class.new
  end
end
```

or even

```
class SpecialHash < Hash
  def [](key)
    has_key?(key) ? super : self[key] = self.class.new
  end
end
```

Comment: Bad, bad idea. Never subclass built-in collection classes for something as insignificant as this. Can you guess why?

Comment: I heard this before, but can't recall why.

Comment: What would be the result of `h.slice(:foo)[:f1][:f2] = 'f3'`?

Comment: `#slice` is a Rails method?

Comment: You didn't try it? `#slice` is in core.

Comment: I did, `undefined method slice for {}:Hash`. Ruby 2.4.

Comment: I'm on 2.5. :shrug:

Comment: anyway I guess slice returns a Hash, not SpecialHash.

Comment: Yep, exactly this.

Comment: In which case you could use a delegator to get the same class back for every method call.

Comment: You could, but _should_ you? Is it worth the effort and potential problems?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171556/discussion-between-kris-and-sergio-tulentsev).

Comment: or even `def [](key); super || store(key,self.class.new); end`

Comment: Only reason I didn't use `super` was in case a key had the value `nil`, I think it would return a new instance instead of `nil`.